# I got a stack overflow error and I can't figure out what causes it

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, maze

I am trying to generate a maze and I faced a stack overflow error while trying to do divide and conquer kind of approach to my 2D array.I will have to post the whole code since I have no idea what causes it and i am very inexperienced in the subject.

this is the details : System.StackOverflowException
HResult=0x800703E9
Message=

this is where the exception happens
!https://imgur.com/a/iwX8pKY
https://www.robinsnyder.com/MazeStaticGif I got the idea from here.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace labirentVize2
{
    class labirentOlustur
    {   public static int delik;
        public static int x=0;
        public static int y;
        public static int N = 30;
        public static int boy = 30;
        
        int[,] uret = new int[N, N];
        public Array girisCikis(int[,] uret)
        {
            int en1=1;
            Random giris = new Random();
            int gir = giris.Next(1, 29);
            if (gir > 14)
            {
                int gir2 = giris.Next(15, 28);
                int gir3 = (gir + gir2)/2;
                uret[0, gir] = 1;
                uret[0, gir2] = 1;
                uret[0, gir3] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int gir2 = giris.Next(1, 15);
                int gir3 = (gir + gir2)/2;
                uret[0, gir] = 1;
                uret[0, gir2] = 1;
                uret[0, gir3] = 1;
            }
            Random cikis = new Random();
            int cik = cikis.Next(1, 28);
            if (cik > 14)
            {
                int cik2 = cikis.Next(1, 28);
                int cik3 = (cik + cik2)/2;
                uret[29, cik] = 1;
                uret[29, cik2] = 1;
                uret[29, cik3] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int cik2 = cikis.Next(15, 28);
                int cik3 = (cik + cik2)/2;
                uret[29, cik] = 1;
                uret[29, cik2] = 1;
                uret[29, cik3] = 1;
            }
            labYap(uret, en1, x, boy);
            return uret;

        }
        void labGoster(int[,] uret)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    Console.Write(" " + uret[i, j] + " ");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        public void labYap(int[,] uret, int en1, int x, int boy)
        {
            int total1 = 0;
            
            Random rand2 = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < uret.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < uret.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    total1 += uret[i, j];}
                               }

                if(total1 > 800)
                {
                labGoster(uret);
                }

                else if (total1 == 784) 
                {
                    Random rand1 = new Random();
                    en1 = rand1.Next(2, 29);
                    x = 30;
                    delik = rand2.Next(1, 29);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    en1 = rand.Next(1, en1);
                    boy = boy - en1;
                    delik = rand2.Next(1, en1);
            }
                
                
                if (diziUstToplam(uret, en1) >= diziAltToplam(uret, en1))
                {
                    y = en1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < x ; j++)
                    {
                        
                        uret[en1, j] = 0;
                    }
                    
                    uret[en1, delik] = 1;
                    labYap(uret, en1, x, boy);
                    labYap(uret, boy, x, boy);
                }
                else
                {   x = en1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < en1; j++)
                    {                        
                        uret[j, en1] = 0;
                    }
                    uret[delik, en1] = 1;


                    labYap(uret, en1, x, boy);
                    labYap(uret, en1, x, boy);
                }
            
            int diziUstToplam(int[,] uret, int en1)
            {

                int total = 0;
                // Dizinin ilk boyutu için 
                for (int i = 0; i < en1; i++)
                {
                    // Dizinin ikinci boyutu için 
                    for (int j = 0; j < uret.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {

                        total += uret[i, j];
                    }
                }
                return total;

            }
            int diziAltToplam(int[,] uret, int en1)
            {

                int total = 0;
                // Dizinin ilk boyutu için 
                for (int i = en1; i < 30; i++)
                {
                    // Dizinin ikinci boyutu için 
                    for (int j = 0; j < uret.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {

                        total += uret[i, j];
                    }
                }
                return total;

            }
            int rastgeleSayi()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int en1 = rand.Next(1, 29);
                return en1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: You might think about your use of `new Random()` everywhere. Each time you create a new instance with the default seed it will generate the same sequence. Best to create one instance and use it where you need it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0#Multiple

Comment: Thank you. I thought using more Random instances would make the numbers more randomized than using one instance at a time. Now I know how it works.

Comment: @RetiredNinja *Each time you create a new instance with the default seed it will generate the same sequence* - that's not actually true..

Comment: @CaiusJard Not strictly, no, but in this use case all or most are likely to have the same seed.

Comment: (Unless OP is using netcore/net5+, which no longer seeds from the clock, though the point about have just one RNG is definitely valid!)

Comment: @emincb please name your methods using PascalCase

Answer (score 1):

The stack overflow error is because you call `labYear()` too many times from within itself. You need to ensure that you have some escape condition where the function can return.

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=net-6.0